# How do I determine which dynamically-generated submit button was clicked in my PHP form?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, submit-button

I want to edit a dynamically-generated form (meaning: I don't know how many rows will be generated).  This content is generated within a `while` loop, and the HTML generated has creates buttons of `input-type=submit`, generating as many identically-named buttons as there are iterations in the loop.

Of the generated buttons, I want to know which submit button has been clicked, in order to provide the user the same form for which it has been clicked.  Disregard the name of the database and password to connect it; the connectivity is fine.

Feel free to suggest any new method to achieve the desired functionality.

The code is as follows:

```
    echo "you have reached your travel details page. your recent travelling details are as follows".'</br>';
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','xyz','xyz','abc') or die("connection to DB failed");
$query="SELECT * FROM travel_details WHERE emailid='{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY dep_date DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("error in querying the DB");
?>
<h1>Your travel details are:-</h1>
<form name="showtraveldet" METHOD="POST" action="edittraveldet.php">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Starting point</th><th>Ending point</th><th>No of passengers</th><th>Expected fare</th><th>Departure date</th>
    <th>Departure time</th><th>Arrival Date</th><th>Arrival Time</th><th>Car Model</th><th>Car number</th>
    <th>Who is driving</th><th>Driver's license number</th>
    </tr>
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $tid=$row['travel_id'];
    echo "the value of tid is '{$tid}'";
    echo'<tr><td>'.$row['start_point'].'</td><td>'.$row['end_point'].'</td><td>'.$row['no_of_pass'].'</td><td>'.
    $row['exp_fare'].'</td><td>'.$row['dep_date'].'</td><td>'.$row['dep_time'].'</td><td>'.$row['arr_date'].'</td><td>'.$row['arr_time'].'
    </td><td>'.$row['car_model'].'</td><td>'.$row['car_no'].'</td><td>'.$row['who_is_driving'].'</td><td>'.$row['driver_license_no'].'</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td></tr><input type="hidden" name="travelid" value="'.$row['travel_id'].' ;?>">';

}
```

edittraveldet.php :-

```
    $travelid=$_POST['travelid'];
echo "the travel id in the variable is $travelid and got the value from '{$_POST['travelid']}'";
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','xyz','xyz','abc') or die("connection to DB failed");
$query="SELECT * FROM travel_details WHERE travel_id='{$travelid}'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("error in querying the DB");
mysqli_close($dbc);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validatewheregoing()" name="wheregoing">
        <h1> Enter your travelling details so that other travellers can join you</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend> Travelling details </legend>
            Start Point: <input type="text" name="start" value="<?php echo $row['start_point']; ?>"/><br />
            End point: <input type="text" name="end" value="<?php echo $row['end_point']; ?>"/><br />
            Passengers allowed: <input type="number" name="noofpass" value="<?php echo $row['no_of_pass']; ?>"/><br />
            Expected Fare per passengers in rupees:<input type="number" name="fare" value="<?php echo $row['exp_fare']; ?>"/><br />
            Departure Date:<input type="date" name="depdate" value="<?php echo $row['dep_date']; ?>"/><br/>
            Departure time:<input type="time" name="deptime" value="<?php echo $row['dep_time'] ;?>"/><br/>
            Arrival Date:<input type="date" name="arrdate" value="<?php echo $row['arr_date']; ?>"/><br/>
            Arrival time at destination:<input type="time" name="arrtime" value="<?php echo $row['arr_time']; ?>"/><br/>
            Car Model and name:<input type="text" name="cardet" value="<?php echo $row['car_det']; ?>"/><br/> <!--make this as a dropdown box for better database matching-->
            Car Number:<input type="text" name="carno" /><br/><input type="checkbox" name="taxi" value="check this box if pooling a taxi">
            Is the car self driven or driven by driver?<input type="radio" name="drivedet" value="Selfdriven" checked=""/>Self Driven<input type="radio" name="drivedet" value="driverdriven" />Driver driven<br />
            Driver's License number<input type="text" name="licence_no"/></br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="taxi" value="check this box if pooling a taxi"></br>
            <input type="hidden" name="travelid" value="<?php echo $travelid ;?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="invite travellers" name="editwheregoing"/>
        </fieldset>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If only you can change your code, I would suggest you put the form tag itself in the while loop, each having the same action pointing to the same url but submitting different information to the destination page. This way you don't have to worry about the button clicked

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    //<form action="sameactionurl.php" name="form_1">
       //<input type="hidden" name="travelid" value="$row['travelid']" />
    //</form>
}
```

Another solution, if you don't want to change your code is use JavaScript to set a common hidden field to the value of the current ID before submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Name your submit buttons in a standard fashion and append a 3-digit number to the end, "button_XXXX_###" where ### is the number and XXX was the original name of your button.

After submission, check your request parameters for all variables starting with name "button_XXXX", and split the actual name "button_XXXX_####" by '_' character, and the "###" suffix will reveal the number of the button pressed.

It might be easier to create a form for each row instead, though.